# Does flutter/dart work on desktop as a native app?

Tags: dart, flutter, x86

I'm interested in learning Google's flutter/dart but I want to be able to create desktop x86 apps with it like with react native. Is there built in support or any 3rd party addons that I can use to make drsktop applications with flutter/dart?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time deciding whether this question is off-topic or not; I won't vote to close it for now but I wouldn't be surprised if someone does (since it veers pretty close to the 'recommend a tool' type of question).

To answer your question though, the answer is sort-of for now. From the flutter FAQ:

> Can I use Flutter to build desktop apps? Yes, but right now it’s not
>   very well supported. We’re working on making this a first class
>   experience. Our current progress is documented on our wiki.

The wiki is [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Desktop-shells) and at the current time of this answer it has some basic information on how to set up building a flutter app for windows, mac, and linux, along with warnings that everything may change at any point and that any plugin needing native code won't work as they only contain code for iOS/Android. The [flutter-desktop-embedding repository](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding) (left-over from before google officially started working on desktop embedding) is an example of how to get started but your mileage may vary as I'm not sure how up to date it is.

Basically, you could start developing a flutter app now on desktop now, but I wouldn't expect to be able to publish that app any time soon without a significant amount of work to get everything to line up properly. Also, publishing it might be difficult at least on windows, and on windows the current shell uses GLFW which isn't probably something you'd want to use in a released app if possible. I'm not from google so I can't speak as to their plans but I would guess (and hope) that there will be some sort of announcement at Google I/O about desktop embedding, but no guarantees.

So TLDR; yes for development purposes but no for deployment.

Comment: The flutter-desktop-embedding repository is still actively maintained; as desktop functionality is added to Flutter, the flutter-desktop-embedding repository is updated to use it, removing any code and tooling that has been obsoleted. The goal is to dismantle it incrementally rather than abandon it.